# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint could not be converted to string when migrate

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSubcategoryTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {``
        Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('parent');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('subcategories');
    }
}
```

thiis my code but when migrate then problem show

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint could not be converted    to string

Comment: `` after `public function up()` seems to be the error maybe

Comment: Has nothing to do with this particular question, but: when do people learn, how to state a proper question? This includes a meaningful topic and proper text in the question itself.

Comment: remove extra comma from public function up(){

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function up()
{Schema::dropIfExists('subcategories');
```

Comment: You might consider adding a few explanatory sentences why this works to your answer as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

> there is an error with your code like you have typed extra comma
> after public function up(){ ``

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreateSubcategoryTable extends Migration
 {
   public function up()
   {``
    Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('parent');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('subcategories');
}
```

}